# Looking for a tool to get style information about an HTML element

Tags: html, css

I am looking for a tool that can show me the **exact** style that is applied to an HTML element. Of course I know tools like the Web Developer Toolbar for Firefox or Chrome. The Fireforx version has the "Show style information" option that goes in the right direction. However this option only shows all CSS that is related to the selected element. It does NOT show, which CSS rules are actually applied.

For example there can be dozends of different selectors that all match a specific element and set a different margin, color or whatever-property. Only one of this selectors "wins" and applies its style to the element. I would like to know which one this is.

I would like to select an element and and see all style properties that are applied to it (margin, color, height, etc.) and in which selectors these styles are defined.

Is there any tool that can deliver this?

Comment: Have you tried [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firebug/)?

Comment: Chrome developer tools currently does that and it strikes out any CSS rules that does not applies to the element.

Comment: When you say "Web Developer Toolbar", are you referring to a plugin or to the built in developer tools (i.e. the one you get when you press F12 or right-click->Inspect Element in Chrome)? Cause the latter already show which style "wins" and where it came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relaible option will be to use the developer's tool. For example Chrome dev tool.[image: chrome Developer Tool]

Chrome dev tool comes with an option called **COMPUTED** which we can find beside **STYLE** tab. It actually shows the properties that are applied on an element.

Note: If you check this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/0xbj2vgk/1/) you can see `#demoDiv` & `.def` both have color property. But the color property with `#demoDiv` got applied on the element. This is because of CSS specificity which determines, which CSS rule is applied by the browsers.Every selector has space in specificity hierarchy.
If two selectors apply to the same element, the one with higher specificity wins & the hierarchy is

1) Inline style.

2) #id

3) Classes, attributes and pseudo-classes.

4) psuedo elements like :before ,:after

There is also a way for measuring the css specificity which I guess is beyond the scope of the question.

Hope this will help you to understand which styles get applied on an element.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this out in chrome dev tools. It shows all of the styling on the selected element.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/4scN5dr.png]

[image]

If you click magnifying glass it takes you to the selector that styled the element.